# How can I absolutely and completely ban Windows 10 updates?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, operating-systems

I know how to pause update to a certain date. But I want to completely ban updates. Whenever I update Windows, all sorts of problems happen. Sound stops working, microphone stops working, 2nd monitor stops working, display starts to look weird, etc and etc. I had to roll back the update already last time. Now it is sending me the notification to update again, and it will likely force me to update again. I want to completely eradicate updating.

This [link](https://www.easeus.com/todo-backup-resource/how-to-stop-windows-10-from-automatically-update.html#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20%22Computer%20Configuration%22%20%3E,the%20Windows%20automatic%20update%20feature.) tells me to type gpedit.msc, but when I do, it simply says "Windows cannot find gpedit.msc. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again". Why is that?

Comment: If you are using wifi, you can set it to metered. It will prevent windows from downloading updates automatically.

Comment: *gpedit.msc* is only present on Windows10 Professional or higher. You're probably using Windows 10 Home.

Comment: To the person who downvoted: just because you disagree with the question in terms of is it a wise thing to do or not, that doesn't make the question a bad one.

Comment: The person who downvoted probably considered this to actually be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) … as do I. It's a bit like asking your car mechanic to fix the horn because the brakes stopped working.

Comment: "Absolutely, completely and permanently" means for at least the next 5 years. You cannot do this. Especially with with Windows Home.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you stop installing updates, all sorts of problems happen too. Software isn't perfect security-wise and a lot of updates you're receiving fix some security problems. It's in your best interest to install security updates as soon as possible.

If you still want to stop updates despite security implications, you can set the *Windows Update* service to *disabled*.

I won't provide detailed steps how to do this because you shouldn't do this. Anyone knowledgeable enough to understand implications of this won't need a step-by-step tutorial. If one needs it, they shouldn't disable this service in the first place because they can't make an informed decision based on risk assessment.

I'd suggest focusing on diagnosing and permanently fixing the problems that surface after updates rather than stopping updates.